# Adding new files to a subversion repository

Tags: svn

I have some files on my local Unix machine that need to be added to a [Subversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion) repository (access via HTTPS). How do I do this?

Doing `svn commit` in the directory just says it's not a working directory.

Comment: svn add * --force

Answer (score 55, accepted):

- Checkout a working copy of the repository (or at least the subdirectory that you want to add the files to): `svn checkout https://example.org/path/to/repo/bleh`
- Copy the files over there.
- `svn add file1 file2...`
- `svn commit`

I am not aware of a quicker option.

**Note:** if you are on the same machine as your Subversion repository, the URL can use the `file:` specifier with a path in place of `https:` in the `svn checkout` command. For example `svn checkout file:///path/to/repo/bleh`.

**PS.** as pointed out in the comments and other answers, you can use something like `svn import . <URL>` if you want to recursively import everything in the current directory. With this option, however, you can't skip over some of the files; it's all or nothing.

Comment: The quicker option is to use svn import as @versionControlBuddy suggests

Comment: @ChrisMarotta that works if you are importing everything in a directory or a single file, but not for a subset of files in a directory. `svn import` accepts only a single path argument. To be honest, though, I did not know back then that `svn import` could be used with an already populated repository. In any case, thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Remove .svn folder from your code to avoid conflict between two sub versions. Then add files.

Comment: I know this an older thread. But why do I have to checkout the folder first? I have no interest in downloading, only uploading. If I try to import, it says "File already exists", while that is true, the file im trying to import is newer and I thought the whole point of SVN was to deal with conflicts like that.

Comment: @nordmanden you could try the `--force` option for `svn import`... no guarantees, though. I don't use SVN myself. My guess is that this simply isn't supported/allowed - so if it doesn't work, you're going to have to ask the SVN folks for the reason.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jan, I'll give it a go.

Comment: @nordmanden my impression is that Subversion merging is done within the repository, say from branch to trunk or from the repository to a working set. So if you do the `checkout` to create a working set, then update the working set, then do a commit, you are working with Subversion merge rather than against it. If the repository is empty then an `import` should be fine or you are creating a new folder in an existing repository where the content is going.

Answer (score 9):

Probably `svn import` would be the best option around. Check out *[Getting Data into Your Repository](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.tour.importing.html)* (in *[Version Control with Subversion, For Subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/)*).

> The svn import command is a quick way to copy an unversioned tree of
> files into a repository, creating intermediate directories as
> necessary. svn import doesn't require a working copy, and your files
> are immediately committed to the repository. You typically use this
> when you have an existing tree of files that you want to begin
> tracking in your Subversion repository. For example:
>
> ```
> $ svn import /path/to/mytree \
>              http://svn.example.com/svn/repo/some/project \
>              -m "Initial import"
> Adding         mytree/foo.c
> Adding         mytree/bar.c
> Adding         mytree/subdir
> Adding         mytree/subdir/quux.h
>
> Committed revision 1.
> $
> ```
>
> The previous example copied the contents of the local directory mytree
> into the directory some/project in the repository. Note that you
> didn't have to create that new directory first—svn import does that
> for you. Immediately after the commit, you can see your data in the
> repository:
>
> ```
> $ svn list http://svn.example.com/svn/repo/some/project
> bar.c
> foo.c
> subdir/
> $
> ```
>
> Note that after the import is finished, the original local directory
> is not converted into a working copy. To begin working on that data in
> a versioned fashion, you still need to create a fresh working copy of
> that tree.

**Note:** if you are on the same machine as the Subversion repository you can use the `file://` specifier with a path rather than the `https://` with a URL specifier.

Answer (score 8):

Normally `svn add *` works. But if you get message like `svn: warning: W150002:` due to mix off versioned and non-versioned files in working copy. Use this command:

```
svn add <path to directory> --force
```

or

```
svn add * --force
```

Answer (score 5):

To add a new file in SVN

```
svn add file_name
svn commit -m "text about changes..."
```

To add a new file in a directory in SVN

```
svn add directory_name/file_name
svn commit -m "text about changes"
```

To add all new files in a directory with some targets (files) are already versioned (added):

```
svn add directory_name/*
svn commit -m "text about changes"
```

Comment: svn add directory_name/*
svn commit -m "text about changes"  this should work only make take time with the Transmitting file............................................ in linux.

Answer (score 1):

Before you can add files in an unversioned directory, you have to add the directory itself to the versioning:

```
svn add directory_name
```

will add the directory `directory_name` and all sub-directories: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.add.html